# How can I directly get data from ViewModel in Activity or Fragment in a nice way?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel

How can I directly get data from ViewModel in Activity or Fragment?

For example, I save data in ViewModel

```
private val _isPaypalPay = MutableLiveData(false)
val isPaypalPay: LiveData<Boolean>
    get() = _isPaypalPay
```

And I want to use a logic in Activity.

```
R.id.nsbtn_pay_confirm -> {
     if (!isDeliveryInfoFine()) return
     if (!viewModel.isPaypalPay.value!! && !isCreditInfoFilledOut()) return
     updateAndPay()
}
```

I have two options

1. viewModel.isPaypalPay.value!!
2. make a function that returns _isPaypalPay.value!!

```
fun getIsPaypalPay() = _isPaypalPay.value!!
```

Or is there any better way?

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of livedata is that you can listen to changes in the fragment and that it will be lifecycleaware. If you are trying to directly access the data in livedata, you are doing it wrong.
Try reading here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata